# Reactive GZIP Decoder

Tags: gzip, reactive-programming, encoder-decoder

Spring-core 5.2 have codec package with decoder such as `StringDecoder` that support reactive programing. the API get `Publisher<DataBuffer>` and return decoded `Flux<String>`.

I was hoping to find GzipDecoder that get `Publisher<DataBuffer>` or `Publisher<ByteArray>` of gzip and return uncomperesed `Flux<ByteArray>` but i didn't find it.

the only library that i find that match my requirement is https://github.com/kptfh/gzip-reactive
but it very immature

any familiar with mature code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the project above copy the code from org.eclipse.jetty.http.GZIPContentDecoder

i add the dependency below (managed by spring boot)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and using the decode method in map function
example:

```
GZIPContentDecoder decoder = new GZIPContentDecoder(2048);
        return Flux.from(input).map(decoder::decode)
                .doFinally(signalType -> decoder.destroy());
```